# Quickbooks - Error generating jaxb classes from qbxml.xsd

Tags: java, jaxb, quickbooks, xjc

I am trying to generate java jaxb classes from the qbxml.xsd schema provided by quickbooks located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Intuit\IDN\Common\tools\validator

I am running the following command:

```
xjc -d C:\dev\jaxb -p com.quickbooks.jaxb qbxml.xsd
```

But I receiving the following error:

```
[ERROR] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'STRTYPE' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
  line 5267 of file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Intuit/IDN/Common/tools/validator/qbxml.xsd

[ERROR] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'STRTYPE' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
  line 5285 of file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Intuit/IDN/Common/tools/validator/qbxml.xsd

[ERROR] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'STRTYPE' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
  line 5303 of file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Intuit/IDN/Common/tools/validator/qbxml.xsd

[ERROR] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'STRTYPE' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
  line 5321 of file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Intuit/IDN/Common/tools/validator/qbxml.xsd

Failed to parse a schema.
```

Any help would be appreciated.. This is my first time generating the JAXB classes

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong xsd to generate to the classes .. the root/parent xsd file seems to be qbxmlops.xsd

```
xjc -d C:\dev\jaxb -p com.quickbooks.jaxb qbxmlops.xsd
```

This generated all the jaxb classes.

Comment: hey can you help me with creating a customer query which gets a user by fullname ? I am using jaxb classes generated from qbxmlops.xsd but not able to create a query using them .